# How to end my C++ game with a print of number of moves used?

Tags: c++

I am programming a game where you have to swap numbers in a 3x3 array from 1 - 9 till every row, column, and diagonal makes a sum of 15. I have succeeded in swapping two digits, printing the array, and printing the sums. However, I am a little stumped on how to correctly end my game once the user succeeds. As of right now it seems like my getSum method is not appropriately switching the bool to false, but does tell user when all sums equal 15.

**Side note:** I have a shuffleGame function that I am still working on, I have been researching the std::shuffle, and looked into a special algorithm but a lot of the terminology is more advanced than where I am at lol. So implementing it is a work in progress, for now I am just trying to solve letting the game end.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class sumGame {
public:
    sumGame (int gameArray[3][3]) {
        
        int num = 1;
        for (int row = 0; row <= 3; row++) {
            
            for (int col = 0; col <= 3; col++) {
                gameArray[row][col] = num;
                num = num + 1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    void findSum (int array[3][3]) {
        rowSum1 = 0;
        colSum1 = 0;
        rowSum2 = 0;
        colSum2 = 0;
        rowSum3 = 0;
        colSum3 = 0;
        diagSum1 = 0;
        diagSum2 = 0;

        for(int c=0; c<3; c++){
            rowSum1 = rowSum1 + gameArray[0][c];
            rowSum2 = rowSum2 + gameArray[1][c];
            rowSum3 = rowSum3 + gameArray[2][c];
        }
        
        for(int r=0; r<3; r++){
            colSum1 = colSum1 + gameArray[r][0];
            colSum2 = colSum2 + gameArray[r][1];
            colSum3 = colSum3 + gameArray[r][2];
        }
        
        for(int r=0; r<3; r++){
            gameArray[3][3]+=gameArray[r][r];
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                if (r == c) {
                    diagSum1 = diagSum1 + gameArray[r][c];
                }
                if ( (r+c) == 2) {
                    diagSum2 = diagSum2 + gameArray[r][c];
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    void getSum(bool game) {
        cout <<  "Row 1: " << setw(13) << rowSum1 << endl;
        cout << "Column 1: " << setw(10) << colSum1 << endl;
        cout <<  "Row 2: " << setw(13) << rowSum2 << endl;
        cout <<  "Column 2: " << setw(10) << colSum2 << endl;
        cout <<  "Row 3: " << setw(13) << rowSum3 << endl;
        cout <<  "Column 3: " << setw(10) << colSum3 << endl;
        cout <<  "Diagonal Left: " << setw(5) << diagSum1 << endl;
        cout << "Diagonal Right: " << setw(4) << diagSum2 << endl;
        
        if (rowSum1 == 15 && rowSum2 == 15 && rowSum3 == 15 && colSum1 == 15 &&                                 colSum3 == 15 && diagSum1 == 15 && diagSum2 == 15) {

            cout << "Board Complete!!";
            game = false;
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "Board Not Complete!";
        }
    }
    
    
    void swapArray(int chosenNum, int swapNum) {
        int row1  = 0;
        int col1 = 0;
        int row2 = 0;
        int col2 = 0;
        int tempArray[3][3];
        
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col <3; col++) {
                if (gameArray[row][col] == chosenNum) {
                    row1 = row;
                    col1 = col;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col <3; col++) {
                if (gameArray[row][col] == swapNum) {
                    row2 = row;
                    col2 = col;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        tempArray[2][2] = gameArray[row1][col1] ;
        gameArray[row1][col1] = gameArray[row2][col2];
        gameArray[row2][col2] = tempArray[2][2];
        
    }
    void setGame (int array[3][3]) {
        num = 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                gameArray[row][col] = num;
                num = num + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void shuffleGame (int array [3][3]) { //Still experimenting with how to                                                                                              //correctly shuffle
        int rand_row = 0;
        int rand_col = 0;
        int temp;
        const int ROW = 3;
        const int COL = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
                rand_row = rand() % ROW;
                rand_col = rand() % COL;
                temp = array[i][j];
                
                array[i][j] = array[rand_row][rand_col];
                array[rand_row][rand_col] = temp;
         
            }
         
        }
    }
    void getGame() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            cout << endl;
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                cout << gameArray[row][col] << " ";
            }
        }
    }
    
    
private:
    int gameArray[4][4];
    int moves;
    int num;
    int rowSum1;
    int colSum1;
    int rowSum2;
    int colSum2;
    int rowSum3;
    int colSum3;
    int diagSum1;
    int diagSum2;
    
};

int main() {
    int turnNum = 0;
    int allFifteen[3][3];
    int targetNum;
    int swapNum;
    bool runGame = true;
    sumGame game(turnNum, allFifteen);
    
    game.setGame(allFifteen);
    game.shuffleGame(allFifteen);

    while (runGame) {
        game.getGame();
        cout << endl << endl;
        game.findSum(allFifteen);
        game.getSum(runGame);
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl << "Enter Digit to move: ";
        cin >> targetNum;
        cout << "Enter Digit to swap with : ";
        cin >> swapNum;
        cout << endl;
        game.swapArray(targetNum, swapNum);
        turnNum = turnNum + 1;
        game.checkWin(runGame);
    }

    if (runGame == false) {
        cout << endl << "Number of moves taken " << turnNum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example Output:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

Row 1:             6
Column 1:         12
Row 2:            15
Column 2:         15
Row 3:            24
Column 3:         18
Diagonal Left:    15
Diagonal Right:   15

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 1
Enter Digit to swap with : 4


4 2 3 
1 5 6 
7 8 9 

Row 1:             9
Column 1:         12
Row 2:            12
Column 2:         15
Row 3:            24
Column 3:         18
Diagonal Left:    18
Diagonal Right:   15

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 2
Enter Digit to swap with : 9


4 9 3 
1 5 6 
7 8 2 

Row 1:            16
Column 1:         12
Row 2:            12
Column 2:         22
Row 3:            17
Column 3:         11
Diagonal Left:    11
Diagonal Right:   15

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 3
Enter Digit to swap with : 2


4 9 2 
1 5 6 
7 8 3 

Row 1:            15
Column 1:         12
Row 2:            12
Column 2:         22
Row 3:            18
Column 3:         11
Diagonal Left:    12
Diagonal Right:   14

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 1
Enter Digit to swap with : 3


4 9 2 
3 5 6 
7 8 1 

Row 1:            15
Column 1:         14
Row 2:            14
Column 2:         22
Row 3:            16
Column 3:          9
Diagonal Left:    10
Diagonal Right:   14

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 6
Enter Digit to swap with : 7


4 9 2 
3 5 7 
6 8 1 

Row 1:            15
Column 1:         13
Row 2:            15
Column 2:         22
Row 3:            15
Column 3:         10
Diagonal Left:    10
Diagonal Right:   13

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 6
Enter Digit to swap with : 1


4 9 2 
3 5 7 
1 8 6 

Row 1:            15
Column 1:          8
Row 2:            15
Column 2:         22
Row 3:            15
Column 3:         15
Diagonal Left:    15
Diagonal Right:    8

Board Not Complete!

Enter Digit to move: 8
Enter Digit to swap with : 1


4 9 2 
3 5 7 
8 1 6 

Row 1:            15
Column 1:         15
Row 2:            15
Column 2:         15
Row 3:            15
Column 3:         15
Diagonal Left:    15
Diagonal Right:   15
Board Complete!!

Enter Digit to move:
```

Comment: First time posting on this forum with C++ code, please let me know if any formatting should be altered or anything I did incorrectly with my question. Thank you for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Don't give us your game. Don't demonstrate *"swap numbers in a 3x3 array from 1 - 9 till every row, column, and diagonal makes a sum of 15."* Demonstrate just your issue, *"it seems like my getSum method is not appropriately switching the bool to false"*. Be merciless in stripping away everything not needed to demonstrate this one symptom. (See also [mre].)

Comment: Yes looks like getSum need to accept the boolean by reference.

Comment: @JaMiT I appreciate that I’ll definitely keep that in mind in future post it definitely makes sense to do it that way! In a past account I had a lot of experience not giving “enough” info so been worried about that. I appreciate the advice again though and thanks for your time.